# Should I use very large/big/other motivation

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I want to use this sentence on my cv, but I don`t know which adjective I should use.

> I have very a **large/big/lot of** motivation.

Comment: I'd advise against using *very a <adj.>*. How about [Extraordinarily Motivated](http://www.inc.com/peter-economy/12-habits-of-extraordinarily-motivated-people.html)? (Sorry, just kidding.) I think you could say *I'm highly/strongly motivated* (*, enthusiastic, and committed to delivering quality work*, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, sorry.  But I can't let you fall into that pit.

I strongly advice ***against*** putting such rubbish in your CV.  The reason it's rubbish is simple: it's a code word for "*desperate*".  And you really don't want to let anybody know before they see you that you're desperate for that job/position/occupation/career.  Your CV should be attractive, yet dignified.

Try to imagine yourself the hiring manager.  Would you actually consider talking to a desperate candidate?  Do you really need a desperate member on your team?

There is plenty of online sources that will (for free) tell you how to create a decent CV, what to say, how to say it, et cetera.  Use them.

Good luck in your search!

Comment: What about if I use it not in CV but in cover letter?

Comment: Same difference.  The online sources that can help you write your CV, can also help you write your cover letter[s].